# how to specify the terminal width in mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm using the mysql CLI, however the result displays always wraps around on my terminal screen. is there any way to specify to mysql the size of my terminal screen?

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find `resize` command but `stty cols 150` worked for me. You would have to execute this command in the bash terminal before you enter mysql command line client.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't seem to have any settings for terminal linesize.  If you're on a system with ksh or bash, try the following before launching the mysql command shell:

```
eval `resize`
```

[note the quotes are backticks] This should set the $COLUMNS and $LINES shell variables to the size of your window and ensure that the xterm knows how big it is.